# HTTP 500 Error When Publishing Web App to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've been trawling through related questions for several weeks looking for an answer, and none of the previous solutions are working for me. I know this is a common (and vague) problem.

I'm hosting a web app in IIS on Windows Server 2016. The application is built in VS2019 and runs fine in IIS Express. The default web site hosted by IIS is working, but when I add a second site pointing to my published application, I'm getting a 500 error.

However, when I check the IIS logs, all I see are 200 responses, which is odd. There is also no error in Event Viewer to give me more details. The best lead I have found so far is that the problem may be caused by the web.config file.

The generated XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MalechusDotCom.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
      </system.webServer>
    </location>
  </configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: bc59438b-f089-4db2-98d6-cc60312db351-->
```

Is there anything else I can check to try to isolate the issue?

Comment: What kind of 500 error page? The HTTP status code plus detailed error code can help Google locate the exact cause for you.

Comment: I think you need some more detailed error information, see [this link](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/07/16/7-tips-for-troubleshooting-asp-net-core-startup-errors.aspx) for info on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem . setting dotnet exe complete path resolved my problem. Try this one:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\MalechusDotCom.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
```

Update above line of code with complete processPath value. Make sure C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe path exist in your system or find equivalent path. this vary system to system.